# cannot seem to connect to mongoDB Atlas

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
Error: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/.
```

I entered my IP address manually, and still getting this message. here is my code.

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const colors = require('colors');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');

dotenv.config({path: './config/config.env'});

connectDB();
const transactions = require('./routes/transactions');
const app = express();

app.use('/api/v1/transactions', transactions);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`.yellow.bold));
```

db.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        });
        console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`.cyan.underline.bold)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`.red);
        process.exit(1)
    }
};
module.exports = connectDB;
```

for the life of mine I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
please assist

Comment: Have you added your IP to the list of whitelisted addresses? Are you also using the correct protocol in the connection string? Is the connection string correct? Is your username/Password correct? There isn't much that will prevent your connection other than above.

Comment: Yes everything is correct. I double checked

Comment: Where's Atlas hosted? Using a cloud provider? If so have you checked you have access to the network? What happens with `ping atlasHost`?

Comment: MongoDB. What do you mean access to the network ? which network,  mine ?

Comment: The Atlas network, your Atlas would be hosted in the cloud (GCP/AWS/Azure), which did you select when configuring? Have you seen this: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/setup-cluster-security/#network-and-firewall-requirements

Comment: Yes it's AWS under the configuration, it's the free version. Created a username and password, added the IP address

Comment: Post your connection string, replacing the username and password and the physical IP, other than your network blocking outgoing connections there's not really much else it can be. Can you run a local DB instance and connect? You may need to do some troubleshooting but you'll get there.